# WAV File ambiguity

Tags: file, wav

I have an 8 bit mono wav file. So each 1 byte of the file represents a sample (1/44100 of a second).
I want to know if the sound, which is heard when the wav file is played, depends only on the samples or does it depend on the difference between two consecutive samples? 
Will the following pair of consecutive samples produce same sound:
1st pair :20 and 22
2nd pair :78 and 80
Please help me...

Answer (score 1):

The sound is the difference between consecutive samples. But in your example 20 22 78 80 you will "hear" mostly the difference 22->78 (if you "play" the four samples). In fact, the values of samples define the voltage on speaker which will move the speaker membrane to corresponding position. The neutral (middle) position of membrane is equal to middle value of sample (in 8-bit case it is 127 or 128 - 0 and 255 and lowest and highest position).

Comment: So if 20 and 22 are played then the sound which will be heard would be exactly same with the sound which will be produced when 78 and 80 are played?
[The sample pairs are played seperately]

Answer (score 0):

It's almost meaningless to talk about the 'same sound' in the case of two 44khz samples but you can think of them both as representing the same frequency (i.e. pitch) but the latter is significantly louder than the former.

Comment: Yes I know its meaningless to talk about about only two samples!!! 
Thanks very much for your answer. Can you explain how to detect the pitch of a group of samples?

Comment: The general technique for that Fourier Analysis (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_analysis). You should be able to find many sound/signal-processing libraries that will do this for you, as will most sound editors, if you're looking to do this interactively.